# Как в Label Studio, сделать так, чтобы текст во время разметки можно было редактировать?

Tags: python, текст, аннотации, разметка, nlp

Я транскрибирую текст из аудио с помощью скрипта и далее хочу выделить в тексте ключевые слова с помощью Label Studio. Но также я хочу, чтобы этот текст в случае необходимости можно было отредактировать.

Тег Text - не имеет атрибута, который бы позволял его редактировать во время разметки.

Как это правильно делать в Label Studio, если необходимо исправить этот текст во время разметки?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]